# How would you continue this predicate logic proof of $\vdash (\forall x) (A\to B)\to (\exists x)A \to (\exists x)B$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, solution-verification, predicate-logic

It's my first time doing predicate logic and I don't even know where to start. I know that $(\forall x)$ means for all X, whereas $(\exists x)$ means that some x exists, however I'm not sure what to even do for this proof.

I know the metatheorems for specialized and weak generalization, and I think weak leibniz might be useful here?

Metatheorems: $(\forall x)A\vdash A$ and if we have $\Gamma\vdash A$, we will also have $\Gamma\vdash(\forall x)A$.

To begin, I think the first step would be to remove inferences, as they are notoriously difficult to work with for Leibniz rule:
$\vdash \neg (\forall x) (\neg A\lor B) \lor (\neg(\exists x) \neg A\lor (\exists x) B)$

My next step would be to move $\neg(\forall x)(\neg A\lor B)$ to the assumptions side, making it:

$\neg (\forall x) (\neg A\lor B) \vdash (\neg (\exists x) \neg A \lor (\exists x) B)$

I'm not sure if this is looking right so far, as I am applying first order logic as that's what I know, with the limited examples I have for predicate logic. How do I even go about changing things here? I know I can temporarily remove the $(\exists x)$'s using gen, then readd them later, and vice versa.

Here are some of the rules we may use:
[Axioms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cakGy.png)
[Axioms 2 and Rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqqSc.png)

Comment: No, it is wrong... From $(∃x)A → (∃x)B$ you get: $¬(∃x)A ∨ (∃x)B)$

Comment: Impossible to answer: we do not know the proof system that you are using. In your previous posts you asked about Resolution, but it seems that you do not know the "usual" Resolution proof procedure. Thus, please be more specific.

Comment: I see. My professor shows a version using two NOT, in form as ¬(∀x)(¬A∨B), because then this can be turned back into (∃x)A∨(∃x)B) after. "For any wff A, we define ((∃x)A) to be a short name for (¬((∀x)(¬A)))" - so then, how can I be changing from ∀ to ∃ and vice versa if I do not follow this rule?

Comment: I am using George Tourlakis' book and it is on the chapter of Predicate Logic. I'm not sure how to show what proof system I am using, but I will add images of the different rules we have.

Comment: It seems to me that we have already provided help to you in your previous DELETED (by you) [post1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4289556/how-do-i-use-leibniz-rule-to-solve-proofs) and [post2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4289607/how-do-i-prove-this-without-using-a-hilbert-style-proof). Why asking help again?

Comment: Those are first-order proofs. I am familiar with those now and have worked with them a bit extensively, but now I am introducing myself to "predicate proofs", including variables like x, y, z, as well as quantifiers (∀, ∃). I'm unfamiliar to this and trying my best but I have limited resource as the textbook I was given only has specific examples.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! I'm curious why you delete your Questions after they have been answered?  BTW, note that there's a (I think careless) mistake in your second disjunct from the right.

Comment: Thank you :) I actually deleted that question because I phrased it all wrong and my work wasn't correct either, I also noticed the answers weren't pertaining to the actual type of answer needed so I thought it would be a hindrance to others looking to solve the question the way I phrased it only to have it answered another way. For example, one of them was a Leibniz proof but the answer had a tautological type of proof, and if someone were to use that type of answer for the work I'm doing, it would be wrong.

Comment: Having said that, the result is proven in Tourlakis (your textbook), **Example 6.5.13**, page 183. So, again: why asking it here?

Comment: May I ask what textbook you are referring to? There is no 6.5.13 in my textbook, in fact predicate logic begins at Chapter 7 and he would not expect us to redo a proof that he has already proven in the text.

Comment: Tourlakis, [Mathematical Logic](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Mathematical_Logic/8jAwgCTgnycC?hl=it&gbpv=1&dq=tourlakis+logic&pg=PR8)

Comment: I see. This is using the "auxiliary hypothesis" which I am meant to solve the proof without.